# Python - Can't import a variable from another file even using common ways to do that

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have read many similar questions here, but i haven't worked for me.

I want to import a variable and it says "ImportError: cannot import name cap" and same for a variable called "resultados".

**file.py**

```
import csv
import cv2
from analyzer import resultados

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
frame_num = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

def save():
    with open("tabelaSTR.csv", "w") as b:
        writer = csv.writer(b, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(zip(resultados))
```

**analyzer.py**

```
from file import cap
from file import save
while True:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, f)
    res, frame = cap.read()
...
    resultados.insert(y, x)
    save()
```

2nd attempt:
**analyzer.py**

```
import file
while True:
    file.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, f)
    res, frame = file.cap.read()
    resultados.insert(carry, x)
    file.save()
```

It says " AttributeError: module 'file' has no attribute 'cap' "

I am using python 3.5.

I have no other trick to solve this, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When a variable is being imported from another file the whole script is run. Are you sure your loops are terminating?

Comment: If you are downvoting please leave a comment as to why

Comment: I'm not downvoting, it is not me!! The whole code was working great, i just moved some parts of it to other file, so I think the problem is all about the importing files. :/

Comment: You got downvoted probably because this looks like a comment, not an answer.